# Menubar Horizontal Issue

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website in which I have MenuBar...

When I am clicking on MenuBar it gets horizontal but I need it to be vertical.
I am posting code so that it would be easier to understand.
Please help my out with this bug.

```
<style>
body {margin:0;}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: gold;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;

  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.main {

  margin-top: 65px;
}

</style>
<style>
.dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
    color: gold;
    padding: 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: gold;
    color: red;
}

.dropdown {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;

}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;

    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: blue}

.show {display:block;}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home"><img src="typ.png" width="62px"></a>
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn dropdown fa fa-bars fa-lg"></button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div> 
</div>
<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With all your suggestions. I got my doubt clear.

For others, the code goes here:-

```
<style>
body {margin:0;}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: gold;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;

  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.main {

  margin-top: 65px;
}

</style>
<style>
.dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
    color: gold;
    padding: 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: gold;
    color: red;
}

.dropdown {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    display: block;

}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 65px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content li {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown li:hover {background-color: blue}

.show {display:inline-block;}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home"><img src="typ.png" width="62px"></a>
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn dropdown fa fa-bars fa-lg"></button> 
</div>
<ul id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <li href="#home">Home</li>
    <li href="#about">About</li>
    <li href="#contact">Contact</li>
  </ul>
<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
</body>
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

It's actually horizontal.  But if you're trying to get it to be vertical have you tried changing the height and width of your navbar?  For example:

```
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: gold;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
      width: 200px;
height: 100%;
    }
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: I didn't try this one, but seems to be helpfull

Answer (score 1):

You should rewrite the `myDropdown` DIV as a `ul` list, containing `li` tags which contain your menu items as `a` tags. That's the regular way to create a menu nowadays.

This will be vertical by default. To make it horizontal, add `display: inline-block` to the `li` items. (And add `list-style:none;`to hide the list bullets)

Comment: Really it helped me out. With the help of you and @MehdiKarimi sir. Thanks